# LDAP: How to bind via system ID/Password and then user ID/password for Authorization?

Tags: linux, ldap, oracle-linux

This command works and give me back a large response with all sorts of information about user with user ID XXXXXXX.

```
ldapsearch -D 'uid=<system ID>,ou=system,ou=users,dc=<domain>,dc=com' -x -H '<ldap server address>' -w '<system ID password> -b 'ou=users,dc=<domain>,dc=com' 'uid=XXXXXXX'
```

However I was told to first bind with the system ID, and then "rebind" with the user's UID/password to check if that user can be authorized.

Is this possible with the ldapsearch command? Maybe it's possible to just use the user's ID/password to bind instead of the initial bind with System ID/password?

EDIT: I think section [2.4.3.3](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41492_01/E41495/html/ldap-auth.html) is what I am trying to convey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in `ldapsearch` feature to do this in one step. What you're describing is application-specific logic; it's very commonly implemented in various LDAP-using software, but would require **two** `ldapsearch` invocations if you're trying to do the same via CLI, just as it requires creating two LDAP sessions through the API.

If you *already know* the user's full LDAP DN, then yes, you can just use it in the `-D` parameter.

However, if you only know the uid but not the entire DN, then you *will* need to search for it first (as you're doing right now), then manually copy the 'dn' from the search output and call `ldapsearch` a second time, with the user's DN specified as `-D`.

---

(One exception: If the LDAP server runs Active Directory, then it'll accept "user@domain"  UPNs as well as "DOMAIN\user" in place of the DN, so you can use `-D 'XXXXXXX@<domain>.com'`. This is not a general LDAP feature, however, and I wouldn't rely on it.)

Comment: Yup that worked... after looking at your suggestion and the output of the first LDAP search with system ID, I realized that I was missing an additional OU for the user. Now I can do it with just one call/user ID and User password. Makes a lot more sense now...